# Weird Error When request.format = :mobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a weird issue when I set request.format = :mobile (so everything is a mobile version), and in one of my functions I do the follow

```
def some_action
 ....
 render :format => :js
 ....
end
```

When I call that function with :remote => true on a form, i get back error 500. What is up with that?

When I don't set request.format (so it is the regular html) and do render :format => :js, it works.

Any suggestions for me to try?

Thanks!

**UPDATE! - Solved**

So, this is weird how to solve the problem. Look at code below.

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.html {render :format => :js}
   format.mobile {render :formats => :js, :layout => false, :content_type => "text/javascript" }
end
```

If there is a better way, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the stack trace from the error?

Comment: Missing template taskers/add_point, application/add_point with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:mobile], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. So it is not rendering the format :js like I want it to. So, how do i solve this?